# How to include a file in a git diff which has stayed the same after two commits?

Tags: git

Let's say you have a file where you add a space, do a git commit, remove the space and do a git commit again.

How do you do a git diff which includes the file.

In our application, if I do a git diff between two tags for instance, and there are such situations (files with commits but stayed the same in the end), then the file isn't included.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is the same, a diff will (of course) not show anything. The best you can do is to list the commits for a particular file between two commits. So in your example, you would do `git log tag1..tag2 -- myFile.txt`.

If you want to see a list of all files modified in a range of commits, you can do `git log tag1 tag2 --name-only --pretty="format:"`

If you are using Linux or if you have the gnu tools installed on your machine you can remove duplicate files with `git log tag1 tag2 --name-only --pretty="format:" | sort | uniq`.

Comment: Mmm, ok, but I want all files that have been changed between two tags. Since we have in the thousand sources, going over each source... Can you do a git log tag1..tag2 and get all files?

Comment: Yup; I have amended my answer to reflect what I think you are trying to do.